# What is this syntax: func funcName(stuff1)(stuff2)->returnType {}

Tags: swift

I've seen several examples of syntax of this form (I'm seeing this while searching for currying in swift)

```
func funcName(a: TypeOfA)(b: TypeOfB) -> returnType
{
   return somethingOfreturnType
}
```

However I can't find this syntax described in The Swift Programming Language ebook. I've just looked at the chapter on functions again and its not there that I could see. Which section of the book is it described in?

What does this syntax mean and how does it differ from this:

```
func funcName(a: TypeOfA, b: TypeOfB) -> returnType
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a *[curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function* -- it decomposes a function of several parameters into a chain of several functions of one parameter each. You can read about them in the Language Reference portion of the book: go to [Function declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_593) and scroll down a bit.

It's equivalent to:

```
func funcName(a: TypeOfA) -> (b: TypeOfB -> returnType) {
    func curryFunc(b: TypeOfB) -> returnType {
        return somethingOfreturnType
    }
    return curryFunc
}
```

[It's also good with sausages.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currywurst)

Answer (score 1):

Swift syntax includes support for currying.  Currying is the process of converting an N argument function into a 'chain' of N one argument functions.  The top level function accepts one argument and returns a 'chain' of N-1 functions.  The body of the curried function presumably uses each of the arguments; for each link in the chain the returned function is 'closed' over that one argument.

Examples:

Imagine you need to compare one value repeated with other values for equality.  You could define a curried functions as:

```
func equalTo (this: Equatable) (other: Equatable) -> Bool { return this == other }
```

and then use as:

```
let equaltoTen = equalTo(10);
// ...
equalToTen (11) ; false
```

or

```
let equalToUsername = equalTo ("Joe Rogan")
```

Another, imagine you needed to repeatedly sort the same array of values.  You could do:

```
func sortingOf<T> (data: [T]) (pred: (T, T) -> Bool) -> [T] {
  // apply 'pred' to 'data' return sorted array of data
}
```

and then example use:

```
let sortingOfNames = sortingOf (["Steve", "John", "Mark", "Billy"])
// ...
sortingOfNames(>)
sortingOfNames(<)
```