# Swift curried function behaves differently from expanded version

Tags: swift, currying

I have a curried function in Swift:

```
func counter(var val: Int)() -> () {
  val++
  println(val)
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25318048/102008) it should be equivalent to this:

```
func counter(var val: Int) -> (() -> ()) {
  func curryFunc() {
    val++
    println(val)
  }
  return curryFunc
}
```

However, when I run the following code:

```
let x = counter(3)
x()
x()
```

with the first one, I get `4`, `4`; whereas with the second one, I get `4`, `5`.

I am using the release Xcode 6.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the first version the body of the curried function is a normal function implementation, whereas in the 2nd case there's a closure. As stated in the documentation:

> Closures can capture and store references to any constants and variables from the context in which they are defined.

In your case, `val` is captured, and retained among consecutive calls.

**Addendum** - if you want to have your 2nd function to behave like the curried one, you should store the parameter in a variable declared inside the function body:

```
func counter(val: Int) -> (() -> ()) {
    func curryFunc() {
        var unretainedVal = val
        unretainedVal++
        println(unretainedVal)
    }
    return curryFunc
}
```

The captured value `val` doesn't change, so the function keeps a reference to its original value.

Comment: But then the curried function is not the same as the directly expanded version

Comment: It's not clear why you need that... however I've updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if that fits with the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: I just want to know what is the general rule for rewriting a curried function in Swift into a normal non-curried function. Other sources seemed to indicate that simply returning an inner function with the same body would suffice, but I produced a counterexample that produces different results. It may be a bug with the current compiler. You are saying more changes need to be done to rewrite it (copying outer function arguments into local variables in the inner function), but I can't find any documentation to support that.

Comment: Are you saying that when the whole body of a function is just returning a nested function, that it cannot always be re-written into a curried function (for example, the expanded function in my question cannot)? My original purpose was to re-write it into a curried function because it would be simpler and shorter.

Comment: Closures capture references to external variables - that's normal, so it's absolutely not a bug. I don't think you will find anything in the documentation about turning a curried into a closure because the curried version is used (among other things) to simplify, just like generics make working with different types simpler.

Comment: My concern is about the function parameter declared as `var` - why would you need to change it, since changes are not applied to the original value provided to the function? As long as you don't use the `var` attribute in function parameters, it should work without having to copy parameters to local variables